# how to simplify my code using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want append `<span></span>` tag in my every `<a>` tag:

**now:**

```
<a href=#>aaa</a>
<a href=#>bbb</a>
<a href=#>ccc</a>
```

**I want:**

```
<a href=#><span>aaa</span></a>
<a href=#><span>bbb</span></a>
<a href=#><span>ccc</span></a>
```

now ,i using below codes to implement it:

```
$(function(){
    var buttons = $("a");
    var text=buttons.text();
    buttons.text("");
    buttons.prepend("<span>"+text+"</span>");
});
```

I think this codes is not good,how to simplify it?

thanks :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think What you are looking for is the [wrapinner](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) function.

```
 $("a").wrapInner("<span></span>")
```

You can find a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MKu4C/).